# CompletableFuture recursive restart on exception from exceptionaly() block

Tags: java, recursion, exception, completable-future

Having a hard time to do a reliable retry of a background task which sends request to let's say mail service in order to get latest emails. Once emails successfully received the execution should continue in `thenAccept()` block - persist emails, however if exception occurs I have to rerun mail retrieval until successful attempt and on success should persist mails and stop. Please take a look and advice if I do it wrong.

```
   private void retrieveMailsAsync(User user) {
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try {
            return mailService.getEmails(user.getName(), user.getPassword());
        } catch (InvalidAuthentication | TimeoutException | BadGatewayException e) {
            throw new CompletionException(e);
        }
    }).thenAccept(email -> {
        mailService.persist(email);
    }).exceptionally(ex -> {
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception retrieveMailsAsync emails, Retrying retrieveMailsAsync:: ", ex.getCause());
        retrieveMailsAsync(user);
        return null;
    });
}
```

P.S please also take a look at how I'm handling checked exception wrapping it into `CompletionException` and rethrowing - the main idea here to handle all exceptions (defined checked and runtime) in one `exceptionally()` block rather than logging them in catch block and return null.

Thanks guys in advance, hope I'm not doing pretty stupid stuff, or at least there is already reliable solutions exists for Java 8.

Comment: Is this independent code or under some framework such as spring , with spring there is a better way to retry ? Also let us know what is the problem , is your exceptionally not retrying the activity ?

Comment: this is somehow easy if you have at least jdk-12, do you?

Comment: Unfortunately it is plain Java 8 without any frameworks (( The question here is wether it is a valid case to handle retry in this way - recursively from exceptionally block ?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but if you want retry until success, why do you throw the completion exception in the first place? You can just loop in the run section until you leave without an exception.

Comment: @daniu, sorry for confusion. The thing is that mailService throws checked exceptions which I had to handle, so I'm wrapping them in runtime CompletionException and In this way I'm trying to gather exception handling login in one place - e.g in exceptionally() block. Otherwise I had to handle checked exceptions and retry logic in catch{} block once and other unchecked + retry logic in exceptionally block. But my solution accumulates this logic in one place. Hope so)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve that via :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String result = call(new User().setName("name").setPassword("p")).join();
    System.out.println(result);
}

private static CompletableFuture<String> call(User user) {
    CompletableFuture<String> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> retrieveMailsAsync(user));
    return future.handleAsync((String result, Throwable ex) -> {
        // or any other Predicate that is satisfied against ex
        if(ex != null) {
            return call(user);
        } else {
            return future;
        }
    }).thenCompose(Function.identity());
}
```

**EDIT**

So what stays in your way to change the code above, for example, to:

```
static ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    call(new User().setName("name").setPassword("p"))
         // chain any other action here, like mailService.persist(email);
         .thenAcceptAsync(
            System.out::println,
            service
    );
    System.out.println("Continue main thread");
}

private static CompletableFuture<String> call(User user) {
    CompletableFuture<String> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> retrieveMailsAsync(user), service);
    return future.handleAsync((String result, Throwable ex) -> {
        // or any other Predicate that is satisfied against ex
        if(ex != null) {
            return call(user);
        } else {
            return future;
        }
    }).thenCompose(Function.identity());
}
```

Comment: @Eugeen, thanks for reply. But using .join() don't we block main thread to wait for completion of asynchronous block? What I really need is to start Future task to retrieve and persist user emails in background while the main thread should proceed further without any delays. And make this things reliable so if there is any exception in the background thread - the task should retry itself  until success.

Comment: @AnMi so, you need that like an async task?

Comment: @Eughen, yes I need this full retrieveMailsAsync() method to be async and run in background, which doesn't stop main thread (just start and forget) and also it must be reliable to restart itself in case of any exceptions from exceptionally block.

Comment: @AnMi see edit. but I do not think you need `CompletableFuture` here, if you simply want to run an async task.

Answer (score 0):

What I meant in my comment was this:

```
   private void retrieveMailsAsync(User user) {
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        while (continueQuery()) { // true for infinite retries, or some other logic
          try {
              return mailService.getEmails(user.getName(), user.getPassword());
          } catch (InvalidAuthentication | TimeoutException | BadGatewayException e) {
              log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception retrieveMailsAsync emails, Retrying retrieveMailsAsync: ", e);
          }
        }
        return null;
    }).thenAccept(email -> {
        mailService.persist(email);
    });
}
```

Ie you just retry in the `submit`ted runnable until you don't get an exception anymore.